# Missing field when publishing a new custom project on acumatica version 4. 10

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I'm developing Acumatica version 4.10 .  I have a problem when I published a new custom project, and I lost the old field on the po screen.  I then want to add a new custom project to add new fields.  So how can I add new field to the PR screen, without losing the fields old ?

*The picture below is when I haven' t published a new custom project* 
[image]

*The picture below is when I published a new custom project already
Field CodeGift is new field which I want add more*
[image]

Please help me, many thanks

Comment: Publish both projects.

Comment: Thank you @HB_ACUMATICA, I will try to do it that way

Comment: Hello @HB_ACUMATICA , can i ask you more a question? How do i add all new (add new DAC and new graph,... ) to file. dll of the previous custom project?

Comment: For DAC you can do Convert To Extension which will generate the code file. DAC and graph in code file you just need to copy paste the file.

Comment: but acumatica version 4.10 doesn't support for "Convert To Extension" , How can I do ?

Comment: After Publishing, the source code file will be in App_RuntimeCode software, you can copy from there too.